# How to correct this weird curve pattern when animating a tikz graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

First of all, thank you if read this post !

I am trying to animate a Tikz graph according to a loop. Here is a MWE of the first method I use. As you can see, it gives a weird pattern when the first curve reaches the limit I set :

**Method 1**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}


\foreach \i in {0.1,0.2,...,6}{
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[    
    axis line style={->},
    axis lines = middle,
    ylabel={$\lambda_t$},
    ylabel style={
            at=(current axis.above origin),
            anchor=south,
        },
    ytick={0.3,1,8},
    yticklabels={$\lambda_0'$,$\lambda_0$,A},
    yticklabel pos=left,
    xlabel={$t$},
    xlabel style={
            at=(current axis.right of origin),
            anchor=west,
        },
    xtick={4,6},
    xticklabels={$T'$,$T$},
          xmax=7,ymin=0,ymax=8,
          domain=0:\i,]
\addplot[gray]  {pow(2,(1/2)*x)} node[above]{};
\addplot[brown, restrict y to domain=0:8]  {-0.7+pow(2,(1.55/2)*x)} node[pos=0.5,left]{$\rho'>\rho$};
     \draw[black, dashed, thick] (axis cs:0,8) -- (axis cs:6,8);
     \draw[black, dashed, thick] (axis cs:4,0) -- (axis cs:4,8);
      \draw[black, dashed, thick] (axis cs:6,0) -- (axis cs:6,8);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

[image: Weird]

I found a way to fix it, but it is not a satisfying solution. As you can see, the node is moving away now. Moreover, for some other reasons, I would like the graph as it appears in Method 1.

**Method 2**

```
    \foreach \i in {0.1,0.2,...,6}{
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[    
    axis line style={->},
    axis lines = middle,
    ylabel={$\lambda_t$},
    ylabel style={
            at=(current axis.above origin),
            anchor=south,
        },
    ytick={0.3,1,8},
    yticklabels={$\lambda_0'$,$\lambda_0$,A},
    yticklabel pos=left,
    xlabel={$t$},
    xlabel style={
            at=(current axis.right of origin),
            anchor=west,
        },
    xtick={4,6},
    xticklabels={$T'$,$T$},
          xmax=7,ymin=0,ymax=8,
          domain=0:\i,]
\addplot[gray]  {pow(2,(1/2)*x)} node[above]{};
\addplot[brown]  {-0.7+pow(2,(1.55/2)*x)} node[pos=0.5,left]{$\rho'>\rho$};
     \draw[black, dashed, thick] (axis cs:0,8) -- (axis cs:6,8);
     \draw[black, dashed, thick] (axis cs:4,0) -- (axis cs:4,8);
      \draw[black, dashed, thick] (axis cs:6,0) -- (axis cs:6,8);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

[image: Not Satisfying]

The only difference between the two methods is that, in the first one I just try to restrict the domain on the curve only with `restrict y domain 0:8`. In the second method I remove this part and restrict the `ymax=8`.

Maybe the solution is to use a double loop with different maximum values, but on my side, it did not work so far.

Again, thank you if you pay attention to my post.

Answer (score 2):

The second method, with `ymax` alone, simply clips the graph, while the former method with `restrict y to domain` suppresses all curve segments that intersect or lie beyond the limit. That is why the wobbling, whose degree depends on the sampling of the curve. Increasing the sampling with e. g. `samples=300` improves the result, but the label is still wobbling somewhat.

A possible fix could be `ymax` alone to clip the graph, and a conditional to plot a saved version of the graph after reaching the limit:

```latex
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \let\fpCompare\fp_compare:nNnTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {0.1,0.2,...,6}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[    
      axis line style={->},
      axis lines = middle,
      ylabel={$\lambda_t$},
      ylabel style={
        at=(current axis.above origin),
        anchor=south,
      },
      ytick={0.3,1,8},
      yticklabels={$\lambda_0'$,$\lambda_0$,A},
      yticklabel pos=left,
      xlabel={$t$},
      xlabel style={
        at=(current axis.right of origin),
        anchor=west,
      },
      xtick={4,6},
      xticklabels={$T'$,$T$},
      xmax=7,ymin=0,ymax=8,
      domain=0:\i,]
      \addplot[gray]  {pow(2,(1/2)*x)} node[above]{};
      \fpCompare{-0.7+2**(1.55/2*\i)}>{8}{
        \ifdefined\savedPath
          \draw[brown,use path=\savedPath]; \node[brown,at=(label)] {$\rho'>\rho$};
        \else  
          \addplot[brown, save path=\savedPath] {-0.7+pow(2,(1.55/2)*x)} node[pos=0.5,left] (label) {$\rho'>\rho$};
        \fi
      }{
        \addplot[brown] {-0.7+pow(2,(1.55/2)*x)} node[pos=0.5,left] {$\rho'>\rho$};
      }
      \draw[black, dashed, thick] (axis cs:0,8) -- (axis cs:6,8);
      \draw[black, dashed, thick] (axis cs:4,0) -- (axis cs:4,8);
      \draw[black, dashed, thick] (axis cs:6,0) -- (axis cs:6,8);
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you AlexG for your detailed answer,

Comment: I got your point concerning the wobbling. 
However, I see the code you provided but it's quite new to me to understand what it changes :)

Comment: As soon as the graph ends at y>8 for the first time, its TikZ path and the label position are saved. The remaining plots simply re-insert both (without executing `\addplot` again).

Comment: Oh I see thank you,
Unfortunatelly I would still need the lambda axis to be greater because at some point I will introduce a curve ending at another level of y.
I will try to increase the sampling as you proposed and see if it does not wobble too much.